# How to show an icon only when certain tab is selected?

Tags: vue.js

For this website I have two login tabs as seen in the image below, and right now it's hard to understand which login tab is selected.

I'm trying to display an icon next to the selected tab, but currently it shows the icon for both tabs. So overall I'm trying to show the icon only for the tab that is selected and if I change the tab, it hides it from the previously selected tab and shows it to the current one.

[image]

This is the whole code that I have -

```
<template>
  <v-main id="login">
    <v-container fill-height fluid>
      <v-layout align-center justify-center>
        <v-flex md4 sm8 xs12>
          <v-card class="elevation-12">
            <v-toolbar color="primary" dark>
              <v-toolbar-title>
                <v-icon left> mdi-login-variant </v-icon>
                {{ $t("welcome") }}
              </v-toolbar-title>
            </v-toolbar>
            <v-divider />
            <v-tabs v-model="selectedTab" grow hide-slider>
              <v-tab
                v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
                :key="i"
                :class="{
                  'primary white--text': tab == selectedTab,
                  caption: tab != selectedTab,
                }"
                :href="`#${tab}`"
                class="pa-0"
              >
                {{ tab }}
                 //This is the icon line that I added
                <v-icon right >mdi-check-circle-outline</v-icon> 
              </v-tab>
              <v-tab-item
                v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
                :key="i"
                :value="tab"
                reverse-transition="scale-transition"
                transition="scale-transition"
              >
                <v-divider />
                <v-card-text>
                  <v-form @submit.prevent="login">
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model.lazy="username"
                      :label="$t('username')"
                      :prepend-inner-icon="
                        tab === 'Windows' ? 'mdi-windows' : 'mdi-account'
                      "
                      :rules="[username !== null || required]"
                      name="username"
                      outlined
                      placeholder=" "
                      type="text"
                    />
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model.lazy="password"
                      :label="$t('password')"
                      :rules="[password !== null || required]"
                      name="password"
                      outlined
                      placeholder=" "
                      prepend-inner-icon="mdi-lock"
                      type="password"
                    />
                    <!-- If error, rended error component -->
                    <error-view
                      v-if="error"
                      :error="error"
                      :is-login="true"
                      class="pa-0"
                    />
                    <v-card-actions class="pa-0">
                      <v-spacer />
                      <v-btn :loading="loading" color="primary" type="submit">
                        {{ $t("submit") }}
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                  </v-form>
                </v-card-text>
              </v-tab-item>
            </v-tabs>
            <div id="version-div">
              <app-version />
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-main>
</template>

<script>
import AppVersion from "@/components/version";

const errorView = () => import("@/components/errorView");

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    errorView,
    AppVersion,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      tabs: ["Windows", "Standard"],
      selectedTab: "Standard",
      username: null,
      password: null,
      loading: false,
      error: null,
      required: (value) => !!value || this.$t("req"),
    };
  },

  methods: {
    resetForm(value) {
      this.username = this.password = value;
    },
    login() {
      if (!this.username || !this.password) {
        this.error = this.$t("warn");
        this.resetForm(null);
      } else {
        this.loading = true;
        const encodedPass = window.btoa(
          unescape(encodeURIComponent(this.password))
        );
        this.$store
          .dispatch("retrieveUser", {
            username: this.username,
            password: encodedPass,
            outside: this.selectedTab === "Windows" ? false : true,
          })
          .then(() => {
            this.$router.push({ name: "home" });
            this.error = null;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
          })
          .finally(() => {
            this.resetForm("");
            this.loading = false;
          });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've actually already implemented the solution in a different part of your code.

Apply the same conditioning as you do to the class binding on `'primary white--text'`. The `v-icon` can be [conditionally rendered](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html) based on the tab selected.

```
<v-icon v-if="tab === selectedTab" right >mdi-check-circle-outline</v-icon>
```

Comment: I was actually trying to do a similar thing, but in a slightly different way and I couldn't understand why it was not working. Thank you so much! Appreciate the help!